# Show office document in android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an android blog app with Firebase Firestore. I want to show a Microsoft Office Word document in the app (because I want to add multiple styled texts).

When the user clicks on an article in the app, an activity will show the specified data. What I mean is that there will be different texts, so each article will have different content. What I want is to show styled text like the ones available in Microsoft Word (bullets and numbering, bold, italic... these stuff) in the content of the article.

I thought of uploading a word.docx document into the storage in Firebase and adding the link of it in the content field in Firestore. But I am sure that it will not work.

Does anyone know what should I do?

Comment: If you want to display a `docx`-file in your own textview you will probably have to correctly parse it. I would suggest looking at RTF instead, which is probably way easier to work with. Or try HTML text which is good enough for the features you suggested.

Comment: HTML can be loaded into the TextView? And btw how can I use it?

Comment: There are solutions for HTML-enabled TextViews out there, the same goes for RTF (look for RichTextView e.g.). With a bit of googling you will surely find something that suits your taste :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have similar thing the only difference is I have shown pdf, but I am sure it can be done for doc also, you will need webView to make it work, I am providing you method that will open the file in webview by google docs, have a look:

```
private void setUpWebView() {
        setWebviewSettings();
        mwebView.clearHistory();
        mwebView.clearFormData();
        mwebView.clearCache(false);
        mwebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mwebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
        mwebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mwebView.setWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient(this));
        mwebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mwebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mwebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        String url = AppConstants.FULL_TANDC_URL;
        if (NetworkUtil.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
            if (url != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(url) && URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)) {
                textNoData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (url.contains(".pdf")) {
                    mwebView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url);
                    mprogressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    mwebView.loadUrl(url);
                    mprogressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            } else {
                textNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mprogressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else {
            mprogressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            textNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }
```

I hope this will help you.

Happy coding :)